# How to parse TOML document with Java

Tags: java, parsing, deserialization, toml

In my Java app I get a TOML document from REST service response as String and I look how to parse it and convert to Java objects.

Ideally I'd like to use some existing mapper library for deserialization, something like Jackson or Gson for JSON objects. Are there any options in Java ecosystem for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several libraries to work with TOML files in Java, such as [mwanji/toml4j](https://github.com/mwanji/toml4j) and [tomlj/tomlj](https://github.com/tomlj/tomlj).
The `toml4j` looks more maintained and has the ability to map the TOML file to your POJO classes, so it should perfectly match your needs.

From its [documentation](https://github.com/mwanji/toml4j#custom-classes):

> `Toml#to(Class<T>)` maps a Toml instance to the given class.
>
> TOML file example:
>
> ```
> name = "Mwanji Ezana"
>
> [address]
>   street = "123 A Street"
>   city = "AnyVille"
>   
> [contacts]
>   "email address" = "me@example.com"
> ```
>
> POJO classes example:
>
> ```
> class Address {
>   String street;
>   String city;
> }
>
> class User {
>   String name;
>   Address address;
>   Map<String, Object> contacts;
> }
> ```
>
> How to map TOML file to POJO classes:
>
> ```
> User user = new Toml().read(tomlFile).to(User.class);
>
> assert user.name.equals("Mwanji Ezana");
> assert user.address.street.equals("123 A Street");
> assert user.contacts.get("\"email address\"").equals("me@example.com");
> ```

Comment: But toml4j hasn't had a release since 2016 and can only parse Toml 0.4.0.
tomlj's only release (at the time of this writing) was in 2019, and can parse Toml 1.0.0-rc1.

Comment: @Alan https://github.com/valderman/4koma is the best I've found

Answer (score 2):

I once also created a wrapper for TOML. Do not remember exact reasons to do this, but it was a lot of fun. Have not promoted it anywhere and no one was using it in years, so I found this stackoverflow post and added this variant as well. Fill free to contribute!

https://github.com/toml-java/tomlj-mapper

### Usage

#### pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.toml-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomlj-mapper</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

#### simple.toml:

```ini
key1 = 'value1'
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

#### Test.java:

```java
import com.github.tomlj.mapper.TomlObjectMapper;

class Test {
    @Test
    public parseSimple() {
        try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/simple.toml")) {
            TomlObjectMapper<Simple> mapper = TomlObjectMapper.forClass(Simple.class);

            // When
            Simple simple = mapper.parse(inputStream);

            // Then
            assertEquals(new Simple("value1", Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), simple);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Simple.java:

```java
public class Simple {
    private final String key1;
    private final List<Long> array1;

    public Simple(String key1, List<Long> array1) {
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.array1 = array1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Simple simple = (Simple) o;
        return Objects.equals(key1, simple.key1) && Objects.equals(array1, simple.array1);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(key1, array1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Simple{" + "key1='" + key1 + '\'' + ", array1=" + array1 + '}';
    }
}
```